# Construct an explicit homotopy demonstrating commuting elements of $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Here is the problem(1.1.10 in Allen Hatcher Algebraic Topology) I want to understand its solution:

From the isomorphism $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)) \cong \pi_1(X, x_0) \times \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ it follows that loops in $X \times \{y_0\}$ and $x_0 \times \{Y\}$ represent commuting elements of $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)).$ Construct an explicit homotopy demonstrating this.

But before understanding its solution, I want to understand why From the isomorphism $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)) \cong \pi_1(X, x_0) \times \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ it follows that loops in $X \times \{y_0\}$ and $\{x_0\} \times \{Y\}$ represent commuting elements of $\pi_1(X \times Y, (x_0, y_0)).$

**Could someone explain this to me please? maybe by giving me a concrete example**

Comment: In a direct product $G\times H$ of groups, elements of the form $(g,1)$ and elements of the form $(1,h)$ commute with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraically the isomorphism is saying a loop in $X\times\{y_0\}$, representing, say, the element $\alpha$, is identifiable with the element: $$(\alpha,1)\in\pi_1(X,x_0)\times\pi_1(Y,y_0)$$And similarly for $\{x_0\}\times Y$.

Such elements commute because: $$(\alpha,1)\cdot(1,\beta)=(\alpha,\beta)=(1,\beta)\cdot(\alpha,1)$$Passing back to $\pi_1(X\times Y)$, this will imply: $$\alpha\cdot\beta=\beta\cdot\alpha$$

The homotopy you need to construct can be thought of as mirroring this algebraic proof.

Comment: I understood your answer starting from "Such elements commute because: ....." but I did not understand all what you said before it, why the loop $\alpha$ is identified like this?

Comment: Why $X$ is multiplied by $\{y_0\}$ and the reverse?

Comment: @Brain We are considering loops in $X\times\{y_0\}$ because that is a subspace of $X\times Y$ and Hatcher is commenting that since loops in $X\times\{y_0\}$ are just loops in $X$ etc. we get the advertised isomorphism. If $f$ is a loop at $(x_0,y_0)$ in $X\times Y$ then $t\mapsto(p_1(f(t)),y_0)$ is a loop in $X\times\{y_0\}$

Comment: Given a loop class $\alpha$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ in $X\times\{y_0\}$, $\alpha$ is identified with $(\alpha,1)$ just by definition of the isomorphism. It’s possible Hatcher doesn’t actually define the isomorphism because he views it as “obvious”, but that’s how it is. Notice $(p_1)_\ast\alpha$ is a loop class at $x_0$ in $X$, and when I write $(\alpha,1)$ I’m technically abusing notation, I should write $((p_1)_\ast\alpha,1)$.

Comment: what is  $p_1$ please?

Comment: @Brain Standard notation for the first projection. Other notations include $\pi_1$ and $\pi_L$ (projection onto the *left* coordinate). $p_1:X\times Y\to X$ sends $(x,y)$ to $x$